# Angular ng-repeat this JSON structure for user to user messaging

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Very simple user to user messaging piece that I'm struggling with the interface in an app to use ng-repeat on the items.

Here is the data:

```
   {
     "ID": 4118,
     "CreatedDate": "2015-08-20T03:12:50.397",
        "recipient": [
         {
           "ID": 13,
           "FirstName": "Heather",
           "LastName": "Martin",
           "ProfileImage": "https://../profilepictures/13"
         }
       ],
 "sender": [
        {
          "ID": 1046,
           "FirstName": "Brad",
           "LastName": "Martin",
           "ProfileImage": "https://../profilepictures/1046"
        }
      ],
  "messages": [
    {
      "ID": 4137,
      "ConversationID": 4118,
      "UserID": 1046,
      "Body": "hey",
      "CreatedDate": "2015-08-20T14:34:42.4716233+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the controller I get the conversations out of LS, one conversation is one record in LocalStorage, the JSON above will represent one conversation.

```
                 $scope.convo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("convo-" + $stateParams.chatId));
```

Here is the structure I am trying to achieve (again, very simple, nothing fancy).

```
  <ul>
        <li class="item-avatar-left" ng-repeat="c in convo track by $index">

            <img ng-src="{{c.recipient[0].ProfileImage}}" />

            <p class="bubble speech">
                {{c.messages[0].Body}}

            </p>

        </li>

    </ul>
```

I've tried multiple variations on the ng-repeat directive.

Essentially what I'd like to achieve is just showing one `<li>` per each message.

Current result: [image]

Console output of a conversation from LS:       [image]

Comment: Let us call the json you showed toto, Do you have convo =  toto or convo = [toto] ?

Comment: Just added that to the post. Right now, I'm certain it's picking up the 5 items in the conversation array (ID, CreatedDate, Sender, Recipient, Messages[] ).  I feel silly for even asking this question, I don't think it's too complex of a problem but I've been struggling with it for several hours now.

Comment: So you do get convo = an array of conversation item where 1 conversation item is containing the 5 items you are showing there ? The only issue I can see is with your data structure

Comment: You need to show us what `console.log(localStorage.getItem("convo-" + $stateParams.chatId))` is outputing. It should be `[ ... "Here is the data: ...", ...]`.

Comment: Keep in mind that convo must be an array, maybe you should do a                  $scope.convo.push(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("convo-" + $stateParams.chatId)));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try normally by `ng-repeat`

**In controller like:**

```
$scope.convo = [
                 {
                      "ID": 4118,
                      "CreatedDate": '2015-08-20T03:12:50.397',
                      //...... as your info
                 }
               ];
```

**In HTML:**

```
    <ul>
     <li class="item-avatar-left" ng-repeat="c in convo">

       <img ng-src="{{c.recipient[0].ProfileImage}}" />

       <p class="bubble speech" ng-repeat="m in c.messages">
                            {{m.Body}}

              </p>

      </li>
  </ul>
```

**NB:** your **$scope.convo** need to be an array